# how to Create clickable category from colors list

Tags: android, android-studio

As shown in the screenshot, I have the list of colors in recyclerView.

I want to create a category like below, when the user clicks on each category, recyclerview shows those range of colors.

[image]

How can i create this kind of color category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a [GridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html), so that your recycler view is rendered as a Grid, in its constructor parameter you set the number of columns, e.g.:

```
mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext, 7);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

// Initialize a new instance of RecyclerView Adapter instance
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(mContext, myData);

// Set the adapter for RecyclerView
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Full example [here](https://android--code.blogspot.com.ar/2015/12/android-recyclerview-grid-layout-example.html)

HIH